# Trouble putting code into a function C++

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a function out of the code that i already have (which works perfectly). I thought i could just put the written code into a function and call it. I am not getting any errors but this function does absolutely nothing(i have emptied the function body now) and i have no idea why. How would I put this into a function? Help on this subject would be much appreciated!
Note: when i test the code in a function (cout << array[0]) it returns perfectly, however, when i do the same thing in the main, it returns nothing.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

    using namespace std;

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
const int COLUMN = 6;

void arraystore(); //function to populate the arrays goes here



int main()
{
    string letterGrade;
    string array[ARRAY_SIZE];
    double scoresarray[ARRAY_SIZE][COLUMN];
    double grade[ARRAY_SIZE];

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("studentInfoFile.txt");

    if (inFile) //I wish to call the function here and have it just store the information into both arrays
    {
        arraystore();
    }


    //this portion of code works great! I need to put it into a function.
    /*
    if(inFile)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 18; j++)
    {
    inFile >> array[j];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
    inFile >> scoresarray[j][i];
    }
    scoresarray[j][5] = ((scoresarray[j][0] + scoresarray[j][1] + scoresarray[j][2] + scoresarray[j][3] + scoresarray[j][4]) / 5);
    }
    }
    */



    for (int z = 0; z <= 18; z++)
    {
        int quotient = scoresarray[z][5] / 10;


        switch (quotient) {

        case 9:
            letterGrade = "A";
            break;
        case 8:
            letterGrade = "B";
            break;
        case 7:
            letterGrade = "C";
            break;
        case 6:
            letterGrade = "D";
            break;
        default:
            letterGrade = "F";
        }
        //cout << array[z] << " " << letterGrade << endl;
    }
    cout << "array: " << array[0] << endl << "score: " << scoresarray[0][4] << endl; //using this to test

    return 0;
}

void arraystore()
{
    //function body to populate the arrays goes here
}
```

This my attempt for the code for the function:

```
        void arraystore()
        {
            string array[ARRAY_SIZE];
            double scoresarray[ARRAY_SIZE][COLUMN];
            ifstream inFile;
            inFile.open("studentInfoFile.txt");
            if (inFile)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 18; j++)
                {
                    inFile >> array[j];
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                    {
                        inFile >> scoresarray[j][i];
                    }
                    scoresarray[j][5] = ((scoresarray[j][0] + scoresarray[j][1] + scoresarray[j][2] + scoresarray[j][3] + scoresarray[j][4]) / 5);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: why void arraystore() does not have input or output? is it populating scoresarray varaible?

Comment: Could you show us your attempt at writing and calling the function? You are saying that when you did it, the function did nothing so something must have been wrong there.

Comment: i am trying yo use arraystore() to populate "array[]" and "scoresarray[][]"

Comment: Your function returns nothing because that's what you've specified using `void`. You should change your signature to `void arraystore(double array[]);` and work with that. It'll be easier than working with dynamic memory, etc.

Comment: i am not sure how to refer to specific comments but , kamilk, when i am testing, all i am doing is writing "cout << array[0]". when i write it in the function body, it prints the name, but when i put it in the main, it prints nothing.

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing. You need to explain what kind of output you are expecting, given sample input, show exactly how the non-working code looks like, and show what (incorrect) output you're getting. The way that the question is currently phrased does not explain what the problem is.

Comment: this is an example of the first line of the file i am reading from: "shane 45 75 23 97" I want to take the name and store it into "array[]" and take the numbers and store them into "scoresarray[][]". So, if I were to say: "cout << array[0]" the output would be "shane". Or, if I were to say  "cout << scoresarray[0][0]", the output would be "45". This code works fine when it is just in the main. all i need to do is create a function that will do this.

Comment: Show us the code for the function that did not work. Odds are pretty good someone can point out why it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

`arraystore` returns `void` and therefore no type/values.

Furthermore all variables in `arraystore` are local, i.e. they are destroyed at the end of the execution of the function.

`arraystore` does not have any reference parameters neither.

How, in mother SO's name, do you expect the function to have any visible side effects outside the function's scope?

In your case one solution could be:

> Pass `array` and `scoresarray` by reference to the function and remove
>   the local variables of both in that function.

Comment: this is the first time I am doing a function with an array, i really have no clue what i am doing. What do i need to do?? I would prefer to keep my array storing code (that took me a day to figure out)

Comment: I understand we might appear harsh, but honestly. You have to learn about programming first. Functions, scopes, return type/values and passing by reference is widely known as basic knowledge; especially in C++. Pass `array` and `scoresarray` by reference to the function and remove the local variables of both in that function.

Comment: @al3xprime: You need to either pass parameters or return values from your function.  Read up on "pass by reference" and "return values" from the function section in your favorite C++ reference.

Comment: removed the intilizations of array and scoresarray in the function and placed them before the main. it is now giving me an error that "array[]" is ambiguous.

Comment: They already exist in `main`. Why do you place them again before `main`? Please read upon the difference between *global* and *local* variable declarations. I would suggest just remove one of the declarations. Keep it either before `main` (global scope) or within `main` (local scope).